# Stuck at Hive Elastic search insert Map 0% Reduce 0%

Tags: elasticsearch, hive, kibana

I have integrated elastic search with hadoop using elasticsearch-hadoop-2.3.2.jar.I am Querying my hive table using beeline.when i create or insert normal table , it works fine.But, when i create a external table for using elastic search like following

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE flogs2 (
    name      STRING,
    city    STRING,
    status   STRING)
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('es.nodes' = '192.168.18.79','es.port' = '9200','es.index.auto.create' = 'true', 'es.resource' = 'mylog/log', 'es.query' = '?q=*');
```

The table is created.But, when i insert data into it like below,

> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE flogs2 SELECT s.name,s.city,s.status FROM logs
>   s;

i am stuck at the following lines

```
0: jdbc:hive2://192.168.18.197:10000> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE flogs2 SELECT s.name,s.city,s.status FROM logs s;
INFO  : Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
INFO  : number of splits:1
INFO  : Submitting tokens for job: job_1464067651503_0014
INFO  : The url to track the job: http://vasanthakumar-virtual-machine:8088/proxy/application_1464067651503_0014/
INFO  : Starting Job = job_1464067651503_0014, Tracking URL = http://vasanthakumar-virtual-machine:8088/proxy/application_1464067651503_0014/
INFO  : Kill Command = /home/vasanthakumar/Desktop/software/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1464067651503_0014
INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
INFO  : 2016-05-24 16:26:51,866 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
INFO  : 2016-05-24 16:27:52,372 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.48 sec
INFO  : 2016-05-24 16:28:52,498 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.48 sec
INFO  : 2016-05-24 16:29:52,562 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.48 sec
INFO  : 2016-05-24 16:30:52,884 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.48 sec
INFO  : 2016-05-24 16:31:53,103 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.48 sec
```

> Note:
>   1.I have tried both HiveCLI and Beeline
>   2.Increased my memory space
>   3.normal hive queries working fine

Please help me to get rid from this.